# Power-cut during upgrade from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04. What's corrupted?

Tags: upgrade

I was upgrading from Ubuntu 18.10 to 19.04, then I went out for a few minutes to look for something to eat...

When I came back home, I realized that there was a power-cut and my computer was in the middle of the upgrade, and I didn't know where did it stop. So I booted it up to see if it works, and it went to the new version just fine, but I couldn't know what was corrupted because I couldn't know where the upgrade was cut.

How can I check if there's any corruptions? Is there a tool for it or I have to do what?

Comment: You're probably fine, but just do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` again. If that fails, do `sudo dpkg --configure -a` or `sudo apt install -f` if the first command recommends it.

Comment: @Jos make it an answer ;)

Comment: I will, I just hope it worked for the OP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're probably fine.

The `apt` process is able to withstand a bit of interruption. Most of the time it can resume an upgrade at the point it left off. If not, it will tell you by warning that a package is in an unstable state. I have not seen that happen as a result of a power cut though.

How to resume a version update: do `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. This will tell you if anything is wrong, and if so, what you can do to repair things. Very possibly the process will simply carry on; if not, `apt` will tell you to do a command like `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (configure the packages that have not been configured yet) or even `sudo apt install -f` (install packages that have not been installed yet and fix any broken dependencies).

You may need a combination of these to perform the complete upgrade. As soon as the command `sudo apt update` reports that there are zero packages to install or configure, your system is fine.

Comment: As it happened, the battery of my laptop ran out at the time of the upgrade to 19.10, pretty early on in the process. After reboot the system was still on 18.10. I only had to do the `apt upgrade` part to get it rolling again.